# How can one bring a civil claim against an unidentified defendant in order to apply for a third party disclosure order to identify them?

Tags: england-and-wales, civil-procedure, subpoena, court-forms

Past answers here have suggested that a claim can initially be brought against an unidentified party like “the man in the blue jacket who did X at Y location on Z date.”

Once the claim is started then many doors open such as soliciting data through third party disclosure applicationsapplications if the identity of the defendant is known by other bodies who would otherwise be barred from disclosing it due to data protection laws.

But the N1 claim form [notes](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/651ec3937309a1000db0a8f6/n1a_0823.pdf) suggest that a name and address are in fact strictly required.

So how can this be done in practice?

Comment: You can actually make the application for disclosure prior to filing a claim.

Comment: @Steve how? (And Merry Christmas!)

Comment: On form N244, under CPR 31.17 (disclosure against a non-party). Merry Xmas!

Comment: @Steve how could one be a non-party to a case that has not yet even been filed? Is this not an oxymoronic contradiction in terms?

Comment: I would say "non-party" means "not a party to the relevant legal dispute or cause of action". It doesn't mean there must be an active claim.

Answer (score 0):

It's been done [at least once](https://www.akingump.com/en/insights/alerts/landmark-u-k-judgment-against-author-of-false-online-review) in the UK in a case involving online defamation, although that case involved filing an additional suit in a US court (as Google is located there).  Once the person was discovered to be a UK citizen, litigation [continued in the UK](https://www.akingump.com/a/web/35460/Bussey-opinion.pdf).